# Android cancel alertDialog with custom layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating an alert dialog with a custom layout and I want to cancel the dialog box when I press one of the layout's buttons.

```
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(GroupAdminOptions.this);
            View alertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.change_group_name, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupAdminOptions.
                    this);
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) alertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserInput);
            Button okButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("QQQ","" + userInput.getText());
                }
            });
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("QQQ","cancel");
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(alertView);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

It is possible to cancel alertDialog when I press cancel button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `AlertDialog` as global variable then you can use `AlertDialog`  inside `onClick()` method then dismiss it.

Try this code after declaring alertDialog as global variable.

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("QQQ","cancel");
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the OnClickListeners after calling alertDialogBuilder.show(), then you can call alertDialog.dismiss() from inside them. E.g.

```
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        Button okButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.okButton);            
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("QQQ","" + userInput.getText());
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button cancelButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("QQQ","cancel");
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to cancel alertDialog when I press cancel button?

yes, you need to call `dialog.dismiss()` in your `cancelButton.setOnClickListener(...)`

Comment: In a custom layout inflated with AlertDialogue , you do not get the dialog object neither dismiss(); method call